# Validity of Bermudan Swaption's Price/Greeks

Tags: models, swaption, bermudan, validation

I'm implementing a lot of stochastic models on my own for fun and I'm quite puzzled about the usual procedure concerning the correctnes of Bermudan swaptions prices and greeks ? How can you tell that the price that you get from the implementation/model is correct?

Should I price the same instrument using the same model but different methods (MC, PDE, Trees) ?

Should I price the same instrument using different models and if they look similar it means that the price is correct ?

Should I try to price degenerate cases of Bermudan swaptions like bermudan swaptions with strike 0 and just see if the model behaves as expected ? I would usually go for this one but I feel that it's not enough, i may be wrong.

I tried to do some research on the case, but didn't found much even when reading some Model Risk Management books. If possible could you also please provide some litterature ?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, but I'd go for 1) find reference implementations in the literature 2) reproduce vanilla prices and 3) - sound development work - pass all unit tests and a good measure of corner cases. HTH?

Comment: Alright so there are no other sanity checks other than correctly pricing vanillas, some degenerate cases of bermudan that basically are vanillas and checking some inequalities between bermudan and vanillas. Thank you